# How do I edit the (runtime) classpath in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ide, classpath

In Eclipse, while trying to start Tomcat, I am getting this error:

`The project: xxxxxxs which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.`

The reason is, I renamed my project from `xxxxxxs` to `xxxxxx` (note no "s"). It is still referencing the old one. Where is the (runtime) classpath and how do I edit it?

I know this is simple, and I've looked.

(*Similar to [Java Eclipse - How do I change the classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375143/java-eclipse-how-do-i-change-the-classpath) but I just want to know how to edit it, not how to solve my particular problem.*)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Found it now that I've asked:

`Run -> Run Configurations... -> Classpath`

This is for the *runtime* classpath, for build classpath editing, see [Java - Problem with the classpath on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520821/java-problem-with-the-classpath-on-eclipse).